# Cannot mock classes, throws Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

Need help in understanding what is wrong with my Unit Tests
    @Test
    public void testDownloadSolutionFileAlreadyPresentInLocalRepo() throws Exception {
        String downloadUrl = "https://artifactory.com/artifactory/com/test-artifact/1.0.0/test-artifact-1.0.0.zip";
        String path = "com/test-artifact/1.0.0/";
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ApplicationContext.class);
        ApplicationContext instance = PowerMockito.mock(ApplicationContext.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ApplicationContext.getInstance()).thenReturn(instance);
        PowerMockito.when(instance.getRepositoryDirectory()).thenReturn("\repository");

```
    SafeFile safeFile = PowerMockito.mock(SafeFile.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(SafeFile.class).withArguments(ApplicationContext.getInstance().getReportsDirectory()).thenReturn(safeFile);
    when(safeFile.getChild(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(safeFile);
    SafeFile result = subsystem.downloadSolution(downloadUrl, path);
    Assert.assertEquals(safeFile, result);
}
```

Inside SC.class

```
    SafeFile downloadSolution(String downloadUrl, String path) throws Exception {
        try {
            String fileName = downloadUrl.substring(downloadUrl.lastIndexOf(SharedConstants.PATH_DELIMITER) + 1, downloadUrl.length());
            SafeFile rootRepoDir = new SafeFile(ApplicationContext.getInstance().getRepositoryDirectory());
            String pkgSolutionPath = "DownloadedSolutions" + SharedConstants.PATH_DELIMITER + path;
            SafeFile tempFile = rootRepoDir.getChild(pkgSolutionPath + fileName);
            if (tempFile.exists()) {
                return tempFile;
            } else {
some logic ...
return new_file;}
```

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.Exception
    at com.system.subsystems.solutioncentral.SC.downloadSolution(SC.java:1017)
    at com.system.subsystems.solutioncentral.SCTest.testDownloadSolutionFileAlreadyPresentInLocalRepo(SCTest.java:832)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

The unit test exits with a null Pointer Exception. **The value of SafeFile rootRepoDir is null**, which I don't get why. I have mocked it then why does it show it as null?
if I remove this line, PowerMockito.whenNew(SafeFile.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(file1);
, then the value of rootRepoDir is non-null

I have added SC.class in PrepareForTest, running with PockerMockRunner

Comment: Try replacing `withAnyArguments()` with an actual argument matcher. (e.g. `.withArguments(any(File.class))`)

Comment: what is your version of mockito and powermock?

Comment: version :junit                  : [
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3',
            'junit:junit:4.12',
            'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19',
            'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.7.4',
            'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.4'
        ]

Comment: when I replace with withArguments( any(File.class)), it says 'The method any(Class<File>) is undefined for the type SCTest.java'.

Comment: `any` refers to `org.mockito.Matchers.any()`. Also add the full stacktrace of your exception just in case.

Comment: nope, didn't work with that !

Comment: Trace just shows the Exception. In SC.java, the SafeFile rootRepoDir is null ! This is the culprit. There is a problem with constructor mocking !

Comment: I want 'tempFile.exists()' to return true. Which means tempFile needs to be a mock. Which means 'rootRepoDir' needs to be mocked, Which means I need to mock the constructor. WHy can't I ?

Comment: Didn't you mention a NullPointerException previously? When did it become an Exception? (Are you sure that is the complete stacktrace?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197446/discussion-between-second-and-pullcommitrun).

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
new SafeFile(ApplicationContext.getInstance().getRepositoryDirectory());
```

you also use `mockStatic` on the `ApplicationContext` class:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ApplicationContext.class);
ApplicationContext mockedApplicationContext = Mockito.mock(ApplicationContext.class);
```

You do not perform any stubbing on that class though, so when you call `ApplicationContext.getInstance()` you get the default return value which is NULL. Then you try to call `NULL.getRepositoryDirectory()` thus NPE.

So make sure you set it up right before you call the SUT:

```
PowerMockito.when(ApplicationContext.getInstance()).thenReturn(appCtxStub);
```

Comment: A) why should it do into ApplicationContext.getInstance() when I'm actually mocking the construction of SafeFile ?

Comment: B) 'Mockito.when(mockedApplicationContext.getRepositoryDirectory()).thenReturn("/repository");'  was added to the above code and even after that I get the same error.

Comment: do you actually need PowerMockito.mockStatic(SC.class); in your test class?

Comment: No. I dont need to mock SC.class. Infact I have deleted it and run the test again. Same error.

Comment: is SafeFile final?

Comment: no, safe file is not final. Infact other test have mocked the constructor the same way i have mocked. And It worked fine for them.

Answer (score 0):

After you solved your issue I tried to reproduce the issue in another class,
however I only managed to confirm that `withAnyArguments` does not seem to work.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Test.class)
public class Test {

    public class Value {
        final String content;

        public Value(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }   
    }

    public class ValueBuilder {

        private String content;

        public ValueBuilder(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public Value build() {
            return new Value(content);
        }
    }

    public static class Utils {

        static Utils instance = new Utils();

        static Utils getInstance() {
            return instance;
        }

        public String getToken() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Utils.class);
        Utils utils = Mockito.mock(Utils.class);
        Mockito.when(utils.getToken()).thenReturn("\\any");
        Mockito.when(Utils.getInstance()).thenReturn(utils);

        ValueBuilder builder = Mockito.mock(ValueBuilder.class);

        // working
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ValueBuilder.class).withArguments(Mockito.any(String.class)).thenReturn(builder);              

        // not working
        //PowerMockito.whenNew(ValueBuilder.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(builder);                                  

        // working
        //PowerMockito.whenNew(ValueBuilder.class).withArguments("\\any").thenReturn(builder);                              

        // working
        //PowerMockito.whenNew(ValueBuilder.class).withArguments(Utils.getInstance().getToken()).thenReturn(builder);       

        Mockito.when(builder.build()).thenReturn(new Value("real"));

        new ValueBuilder(Utils.getInstance().getToken()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: ApplicationContext.java is added on PrepareforTest Annotation.  There are other tests which mock the constructor of SafeFile the same way I have done. But SafeFile abc = new SafeFile(xyz) always returns them the mockedObject. For me it returns null.

Comment: SafeFile solutionZIP = new SafeFile(rootRepoDir.getChild(pkgSolutionPath).toPath()
                .resolve(artifactId + SharedConstants.HYPHEN + version + ExtensionPackageConstants.ZIP_EXT).toAbsolutePath().toString()); This returns mockedSafeFile in place of solutionZIP ( IN OTHER TEST CASES)